# React Form Won't Show Anything to the Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React form in javascript that I can't seem to get to work. Its extremely simple, but nothing will load to the browser.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


function signUp() {
  function handle () {console.log(document.getElementById('year').value);
}
return (
  <>
  <select id="year">
      <option>Freshamn</option>
      <option>Freshamn</option>
  </select>

  <div>Name</div>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div>Email</div>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div>Password</div>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div><input type="checkbox"/> Remember me</div>
  <button onClick={handle}>Submit</button>
  </>
)
};

ReactDOM.render(<signUp/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. I suggest simplifying to figure out what the problem is. For example, reduce your component to `<p>Hello, World!</p>` and see if you can get it to render in the page.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that is not the reason. Inputs work without a form tag.

Comment: Side note: this won't fix your problem, but I suggest that you avoid using `document.getElementById()` in a React app. This is an anti-pattern in ReactJS. Instead, learn about props and state which are the way we keep track of data in React.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, the closing } before the return statement is for the handle() function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many problems. I would try changing `signUp` to `SignUp` (change the capitalization). Also, you shouldn't use `document.getElementById`. You should give the input a value of a state and use that state value instead.

Comment: This is it! I don't know why, but changing changing signUp to SignUp solved it. I really don't know why though. Aren't we using camel case here?

Comment: Also, I filled in the <> </> with <div> & </div>

Comment: @Scorpionz Try keeping the `<div>` tag and changing the name back to `signUp`.

Comment: In React, custom components need an uppercase first letter because it differentiates it from a normal element. For example, if you had a function named div, how would it know from the HTML div element and your custom component.

Comment: @Shivam That makes perfect sense! Thank you x10

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That caused the webpages to not load. Like Shivam said, my custom component needs to be differentiated from a normal javascript element.